# Como excluir um registro sem afetar a consulta?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho duas tabelas PRODUTO e CLIENTES. Estou usando *inner join* para ligá-las nas minhas consultas.

Eu chamo o produto e ele exibe o produto, pega o cliente da tabela CLIENTES e exibe junto na consulta.

Depois de excluir o cliente, o produto não é mais exibido, pois o cliente não existe mais. Como faço para continuar exibindo o produto mesmo sem existir o cliente?

Comment: Acredito que apenas trocando o `Inner Join` por um `Left Join` deve funcionar.

Comment: O Wakim provavelmente está certo mas precisamos ver como está sua *query*.

Comment: Poste sua consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Sempre que quiser retornar valores que estão presentes em ambas as tabelas, utilize `INNER JOIN`.

```
From tbesquerda inner join tbdireita
on tbesquerda.codigo = tbdireita.codigo

  ------------------- 
  |A.NOME | B.VALOR | 
  ------------------- 
1.|UM     | 1.000   | 
2.|UM     | 2.000   | 
3.|UM     | 5.000   | 
4.|DOIS   | 4.000   | 
5.|DOIS   | 9.000   | 
6.|TRES   | 7.000   | 
7.|CINCO  | 4.000   | 
  -------------------
```

Sempre que quiser retornar todos os valores que estão presentes na tabela da esquerda, utilize `LEFT JOIN`.

```
From tbesquerda left join tbdireita
on tbesquerda.codigo = tbdireita.codigo

  ------------------- 
  |A.NOME | B.VALOR | 
  ------------------- 
1.|UM     | 1.000   | 
2.|UM     | 2.000   | 
3.|UM     | 5.000   | 
4.|DOIS   | 4.000   | 
5.|DOIS   | 9.000   | 
6.|TRES   | 7.000   | 
7.|QUATRO | <NULL>  | 
8.|CINCO  | 4.000   | 
  -------------------
```

Sempre que quiser retornar todos os valores que estão presentes na tabela da direita, utilize `RIGHT JOIN`.

```
From tbesquerda right join tbdireita
on tbesquerda.codigo = tbdireita.codigo

  ------------------- 
  |A.NOME | B.VALOR |
  ------------------- 
1.|UM     | 1.000   | 
2.|UM     | 2.000   | 
3.|UM     | 5.000   | 
4.|DOIS   | 4.000   | 
5.|DOIS   | 9.000   | 
6.|TRES   | 7.000   | 
7.|CINCO  | 4.000   | 
8.|<NULL> | 7.000   |  
  -------------------
```

Sempre que quiser retornar todos os valores que estão em ambas as tabela mesmo que que seja null, utilize `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
From tbesquerda full outer join tbdireita
on tbesquerda.codigo = tbdireita.codigo

  ------------------- 
  |A.NOME | B.VALOR | 
  ------------------- 
1.|UM     | 1.000   | 
2.|UM     | 2.000   | 
3.|UM     | 5.000   | 
4.|DOIS   | 4.000   | 
5.|DOIS   | 9.000   | 
6.|TRES   | 7.000   | 
7.|QUATRO | <NULL>  | 
8.|CINCO  | 4.000   | 
9.|<NULL> | 7.000   | 
  -------------------
```

---

Seu exemplo

```
Select  tbproduto.produto, 
        tbcliente.cliente

From tbproduto left join tbcliente
on tbproduto.codigo = tbcliente.codigo
```

Agora modele a consulta para o que você esta buscando.